# Nonmeasurable set and G-delta set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I've included the problem from Royden and my attempted solution. Hopefully, someone can let me know if my solution is correct or not. If not, can help!

**Problem:** $E$ nonmeasurable such that $m^*(E) < + \infty$. Given that $G$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set such that $E \subseteq G$ and $m^*(E) = m^*(G)$. Show that $m^*(G \setminus E) > 0$.

(my) **Solution:** By way of contradiction, assume that $m^*(G \setminus E) \leq 0$, meaning we have  $m^*(G \setminus E) = 0$. Since $E \subseteq G$ we can write
$$G \cap E = G \implies m^*(G \cap E) = m^*(G). \quad (i)$$
We can also rewrite $G \setminus E$ as
$$G \setminus E = G \cap E^c \implies m^*(G \setminus E) = m^*(G \cap E^c) = 0. \quad (ii)$$
By (i) we can write
$$m^*(G) = m^*(G \cap E)$$
$$m^*(G) = m^*(G \cap E) + 0$$
By (ii) we can replace $0$ by $m^*(G \cap E^c)$, hence, we get
$$m^*(G) = m^*(G \cap E) + m^*(G \cap E^c).$$
Therefore, $E$ is measurable, a contradiction. Hence, our assumption that $m^*(G \setminus E) \leq 0$ was flase. Hence, $m^*(G \setminus E) > 0$.

My concerns about the solution is that this holds only for $G$, i.e. only for $G_{\delta}$ sets, whereas for $E$ to be measurable it needs to holds for every subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $G$ is measurable because it is a Borel set. If $m(G\setminus E)=0$ then $G\setminus E$ is mesurebale (with respect to the Caratheodory completion of $\mu$) and so, $E=G\setminus(G\setminus E)=G\cap E=E$ is measurable (with respect to the completion of $\mu$.  The assumption on $G$ may be replaced by $G$ is measurable with respect the Caratheodory completion of $\mu$.

Comment: $E$ is measurable if for *any subset* $A$ of the ambient space $m^*(A\cap E)+m*(A\setminus E)$=m^*(A)$, not only for a particular set $G$. And, you didn't use the $G_\delta$ assumption.